# jQuery load() not functioning as expected

Tags: php, jquery

I've a jquery script that call the number2.php page, which is supposed to execute and show the result in a `<div>`. The problem is that is not working. Can you help me? Thanks.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function() {
            if ($('#taille').val() != 0) {
                var param = 'l=' + $('#taille').val();
            }
            else {
                var param = 'b=' + $('#datepicker').val() + 'c=' + $('#datepicker1').val() + 'num' + $('#num').val();
            }
            $('#retour').load('number2.php', param);
        );  
    });
</script>
```

Comment: En anglais s'il vous plaît

Comment: Translation : 

I've a jquery script that call the number2.php page, which is supposed to execute and show the result in a <div>. The problem is that is not working. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: @wiwi, what do you want to say by the fact that it doesn't work? Did you use the console to see if there is any javascript error or if the request was launched?

fr trans : wiwi, qu'entends-tu par ne fonctionne pas? As-tu regardé la console javascript pour voir si il y'avait des erreurs et si la requête avait bien été lancé?

Thanks.

Comment: no the request is not launched i've got the same page refreched instead !

Comment: Note that you're missing a closing `}` on your click handler function.

Comment: thx   @RoryMcCrossan now it works but after loading number2.php my main page is refreshed and i mose the result !!!

Comment: I've added an answer for you which should solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a syntax error; it's missing closing `}` in the click handler function.

> now it works but after loading number2.php my main page is refreshed and i lose the result !!!

In this case, you should hook to the `submit` event of the `form` element and call `preventDefault()` on the event to prevent the normal form submission. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myForm').submit(function(e) { // change #myForm to target the <form>
        e.preventDefault();
        var param = {};
        if ($('#taille').val() != 0) {
            param.l = $('#taille').val()
        }
        else {
            param.b = $('#datepicker').val();
            param.c = $('#datepicker1').val();
            param.num = $('#num').val();
        }
        $('#retour').load('number2.php', param);
    });  
});
```

Comment: sorry to bother but when i test my parameters in php page i get l and num  but not b nor c  that's strange no !!! knowing that the code was working fine before i added jquery i mean i had the date result before

Comment: @wiwi: Try the code now -- there was an issue with the `param` variable being out of scope, so in your call to `load`, `param` was `undefined`. It should now contain the values you need.

Comment: @wiwi your querystring was missing the `&` character to delimit the key/value pairs. Try my updated version.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: No problem. I might also argue incorporating `$.param({ ... })` instead of manually building a query string, but I think you have enough to get OP back on the right track.

Comment: I agree, plus it's a 2 second change :) OP - I'd suggest passing the `param` as an object and let jQuery do the serialisation for you - see the latest update.

Comment: how van i collect these parameters in the next page cause it's not working for me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript, or if you're sending the params to a PHP page, you can retrieve them as you would any standard GET parameter.

Comment: I'm using GET parameter and i've changed my jquery code a thousend times the result is allways the same i get only one parameter which is 'l' and none of the others

Comment: That would suggest the `$('#taille').val() != 0` condition is always true.

Comment: ifound the problem it's what you said earlier " the & missing " i just didn't get it any way thx alot @RoryMcCrossan you've been so helpful :D